# How to remove Auto Generated Divs in Container in ExtJs

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, extjs

I want to remove Extra div's from Extjs Containers. I have many containers on my view but I dont want two extra divs in container. These two divs generate every time in container so I am facing some problems when I am applying bootstrap on it.

These two div contain `data-ref="innerCt"` and `data-ref="outerCt"`.

Thank You

Comment: Don't remove them, they are required by the framework for sizing.

Comment: But is there any way to remove? @Evan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This markup depends on layout. For example `fit` doesn't render additional divs, but it can display only one component at once. You can achieve similar behavior by defining custom layout. Example:

```
Ext.define('Ext.layout.container.Null', {
    alias: ['layout.null', 'layout.nullcontainer'],
    extend: 'Ext.layout.container.Container',
    type: 'nullcontainer',

    reserveScrollbar: false,
    managePadding: false,
    manageOverflow: false,
    needsItemSize: false,
    setsItemSize: false,

    renderTpl: [
        '{%this.renderBody(out,values)%}'
    ]
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bzm1s8ye/2/

Comment: Reason for downvote: Ext layouts are *very* complex and should not be messed with unless absolutely necessary. This is a bad advice.

Comment: @AlexTokarev What you said is just ridiculous - complexity is a relative concept. Even if it is complex, nobody said it will be easy. Additionally I don't mess with layouts, I've created new by extending base one and defaults some properties. You can achieve the same by using `layout: 'container'` and configuring it. Question was what can be done with this extra divs - and answer point exactly what can be done. I don't know other way to do that - you can provide your own answer if you do.

Comment: Furthermore inheritance is one of major concepts of OOP, and AFAIK this framework is meant to be OOP, and what I've did is inheritance at its best. I've been using customized layouts since Ext JS 3, and I don't find it any more complex than other code in Ext JS.
Lastly mixing ExtJS with bootstrap (which has his own layout system) may occur easier when you disable or limit one layout system, so having something like `nulllayout` might actually turn out to be easiest way to make those two frameworks work together.

Comment: This has nothing to do with OOP. Ext JS layout engine has been tuned to be as performant as possible while remaining as flexible as it is; as a consequence its mechanism is not as tolerant to customizations as other parts of the framework. While you might have had success using customized layouts in the past, I had to troubleshooot *a lot* of layout issues for our customers and my advice is to avoid customizing layouts without a very valid reason. Removing DOM nodes used by layouts just because you don't like them is not a valid reason to mess with layouts.

Comment: Also keep in mind that while you might know framework internals enough to make customized layouts work, this kind of knowledge is certainly not something an average user would possess. Recommending to use custom layouts suggests that it is easy and predictable while it is not; it will do more harm than good in the hands of an average Joe who will cut and paste your snippet first and then spend weeks trying to find why layout failures are cropping up somewhere else. This is a very bad advice indeed.

Comment: Of course it has a lot to do with OOP. `Ext.layout.container.Container` is public and it is a base class for all layouts, so it can be extended. The need for customizing layouts shows, that it is not as flexible as you think. For me changing markup is for me reason to do customization, as it is with components, especially when you need to make that work along with other framework (bootstrap for example). You don't know what constraints in that case bootstrap forces, so you shouldn't say that it is not enough reason for changing markup.

Comment: Even if performance will be worse, any solution is better than none. When you have something that work, then you might thing about performance. In addition - for big pages, when you have lot of containers it might actually increase performance, because of reduced overhead. I say it already in the past in Ext, that markup was unnecessarily extensive, and just changing templates resulted in much performance improvement. Everything depends on context, and concrete use.

Answer (score 3):

Having reviewed the source code for 6.0.2, I believe it is only necessary to set `layout: 'container'` on the container for which you don't want the extra layout divs. All the other properties mentioned in Krzysztof's answer are only defined on Ext.layout.container.Auto which is a subclass of Ext.layout.container.Container, and therefore there is no need to include them.